# Is there a way to avoid this crippling prompt effect in Terminal on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal

Here's a short video demo of the problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOxod-ViZUw&feature=youtu.be

Rather than crippling the prompt, I prefer the caret to move to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. It turned out I was not escaping color codes correctly.

After using `\[\e[0;31m\]` instead of `\e[0;31m`, for example, the problem got fixed.